# Counting the number of Worksheets with name that starts with specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to count the number of worksheets with similar names (e.g. all that start with "East").

Here's the code I'm using to count the sheets:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myTotal As Long
Dim wsTotal As Long

For Each wb In Workbooks
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like "20 Out of Court" & "*" Then myTotal = myTotal + 1
    Next ws
Next wb
wsTotal = myTotal
```

Sometimes it doubles the worksheet total on certain machines.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below codee :

```
Sub sample()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myTotal As Long
    Dim wsTotal As Long

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            Debug.Print ws.Name
            If InStr(1,left(ws.Name,4), "East", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' will check for start with "East"..
                myTotal = myTotal + 1
            End If
        Next ws
    Next wb
    wsTotal = myTotal
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure `InStr` checks that worksheet name starts with `East`. I think it just checks if `East` is in the string. Using your code `InStr` returns `True` for a worksheet named `NorthEast`

Comment: You can also compare left(lcase(ws.name),4) = "east"

Comment: Apologies - you are right. I tested code without the `1` to denote start position.